# Need explanation for array destructuring with spread operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring, spread-syntax

How does the spread operator within the array destructuring of `y3` work?

The result would contain both 'lizard' and 'spock', but because of the spread operator around the square brackets, it somehow only contains 'lizard'.

Thanks in advance for the help.

```js
function myFunction(y1, y2, ...y3) {
  console.log(y3)
  const [x1, ...[result]] = y3;
  console.log(result);
}

const myArray = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors', 'lizard', 'spock'];

myFunction(...myArray);
```

Comment: It's the same as `const [x1, result] = y3;`.

Comment: @caTS ah, now I see. It seems a little redundant to create an array and then immediately spread it, because it achieves nothing. But if you were to destructure an array of 3 elements, but only put two variables in the destructuring, it will only give you the first two elements of that array. Makes sense now, lol!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `const` declaration:

```
const [x1, ...[result]] = y3;
```

the variable `x1` will pluck the first element of array `y3`.  The spread, then, will refer to the rest of `y3`. After the spread syntax, you have another destructuring request, this time to pluck out the first element of the array "created" by the spread (that is, the last two elements of `y3`). That first element is "lizard".

Without the inner square brackets, `result` would be the real (yes, created) array `["lizard", "spock"]`.

Note that spread syntax is not part of the expression grammar, and `...` is not an operator.

Comment: The spread doesn't really create an array; I couldn't think of a better way to describe what's happening.

Comment: the spread in this case is functioning as a  [rest property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_property) which is further destructured. (unnecessary in this case as per @caTS comment, but `const [x1, ...[,result]] = y3;` would make it more apparent)

Comment: Ah, so in the same way, putting [x1, x2] will only pluck the first two elements of y3, so too does [result] pluck only the first element of the newly created array containing ['lizard', 'spock']. Is that correct @Pointy?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. In a destructuring assignment like that, the `[ ]` (and, in other cases, `{ }`) describe the "shape" of the source object, and guide the spread as it "takes apart" the source and assigns values to the local variables.